# Why is the "Create Virtual Device" button is disabled in my AVD Manager?

Tags: android-studio, avd-manager, vdi

I've seen questions regarding button disabled in AVD Manager. But all of them are after when you click "Create Virtual Device" button.

I am on VDI and I am unable to click the "Create Virtual Device" button itself.

Android: v111.0(R)
Android Studio: v4.2.1
Android Emulator: v30.6.5

Comment: Did you able to screenshot your issue? Also, your Android Studio version might helps

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your system is not compatible with it. Take a look at the official guide.
Here you will find all the explanations about the emulator.

[Run apps on the Android Emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator)

**Here is some requirements:**

Requirements and recommendations

The Android Emulator has additional requirements beyond the basic system requirements for Android Studio, which are described below:

- SDK Tools 26.1.1 or higher
- 64-bit processor
- Windows: CPU with UG (unrestricted guest) support
- HAXM 6.2.1 or later (HAXM 7.2.0 or later recommended)